# (All variants) How to manipulate several variables?

Tags: bash, list, variables, newline

Let's suppose I have two variables: var1 and var2. Each of them has equal number of lines.
I.e.:

```
$ echo "$var1"
a
b
c
d

$ echo "$var2"
1
2
3
4
```

How to echo these variables in combination:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

Comment: Why do you have variables with newlines like this? why don't you have arrays instead? (it would be much simpler with arrays).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Can you tell how to make two arrays of such variables and then manipulate them?

Comment: array1=( $(echo $var1) )

Comment: @user2791506 where do your data come from? if they come from a file, `mapfile` might be a good option.

Comment: @BruceK, that's a very poor practice -- not just inefficient (using a subshell), but also think of what happens if `$var1` contains a glob expression (particularly one that matches files, but ones that don't can be problematic as well if `nullglob` is enabled). bash 4's `readarray -t array1 <<<"$var1"` is much safer, as is `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array1 <<<"$var1"` in bash 3.x.

Comment: CharlesDuffy, user000001, gniourf_gniourf: thank you guys, all your answers are brilliant. I learned a lot today

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would be to have arrays instead of variables that contain newlines.

2 cases:

- Your data comes from the output of a process `process` or a file `file`: use `mapfile` to set your arrays as:

  ```
  mapfile -t var1 < <(process blah blah)
  ```

  or

  ```
  mapfile -t var1 < file
  ```
- You built your data yourself. Then just build your arrays, e.g.,

  ```
  var1=( a b c d )
  var2=( 1 2 3 4 )
  ```

---

Assuming you have two arrays `var1` and `var2`, here's how you can output them. I understand you want some formating being done, so I will output your data with prepending `gorilla`, inserting `likes` and appending `bananas`:

```
for((i=0;i<${#var1[@]}&&i<${#var2[@]};++i)); do
    printf "gorilla %s likes %s bananas\n" "${var1[i]}" "${var2[i]}"
done
```

This would output:

```
gorilla a likes 1 bananas
gorilla b likes 2 bananas
gorilla c likes 3 bananas
gorilla d likes 4 bananas
```

---

As mentioned by Charles Duffy in a comment: `mapfile` appeared in bash 4. But hey, seriously, we're now in 2014 and bash 4.0 was released in 2009 (iirc)...

Comment: Might document the caveat that readarray / mapfile is a bash 4.x-ism. Otherwise, looks good to me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Post edited accordingly, with a minute pinch of trolling.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the paste command and process subsitution:

```
$ paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2")
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to add something before/between/after them? i.e: title a line 1

Comment: BTW, are there any other options without process substitution? I have bash 3 compiled with limited abilities.

Comment: @user2791506 Then I don't think it is easy/possible. Go with gniourf_gniourf's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand that the only reason gniourf_gniourf's answer hasn't been accepted is a lack of bash 3.x compatibility? If so, see this variant:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array1 <<<"$var1"
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array2 <<<"$var2"
for ((i=0; i < ${#array1[@]} && i < ${#array2[@]}; ++i)); do
    printf "gorilla %s likes %s bananas\n" "${array1[i]}" "${array2[i]}"
done
```